# iPhone (iOS) mistakes my router (mifi) as needing a login page

Tags: iphone, ios, network, wifi

When using my iOS 8 iPhone 6 with a cellular mifi, it sometimes thinks this device has some sort of webpage login page, the way public wifi does (I guess sometimes called a landing page).  However, it does not.  Is there a way in iOS I can mark a SSID as never needing a login page?

I suspect the reason it does this is this:

1. The mifi gives out DHCP before it has connected to the internet via cellular
2. iOS sees that it has a local IP address but can't reach the interent via some sort of test
3. Thus iOS assumes this is a scenario where you have to login, and tries to bring up a landing page - its blank but has the domain name that the router uses a shortcut to get to its web interface

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you log into any wifi router, immediately thereafter the OS (iOS or MacOS) tries to resolve the DNS for www.apple.com, and then attempts to navigate to this page:

apple.com/library/test/success.html

(Or one of a handful of similar ones distributed around the 'net.) The page is [very simple](https://discussions.apple.com/message/20279540#20279540) and basically just responds with the word "Success". If they do not get that, or it times out, they assume that you're on a captive router that needs a login. In that case they navigate to the IP of your router/gateway, which in your case brings up the settings, but in a captive system brings up the login page.

Fixing it seems to be a bit of a dark art. Try [this solution](https://discussions.apple.com/message/20279540#20279540) first and see if it helps.

Comment: Really good data on how the mechanism works, thank you! But the solutions linked to cover situations where the process is not working at all - I think in my case its not working legitimately due timing of the cell network routing to the net versus the private wifi network issuing dhcp, but I want some way to tell iOS "skip these steps" (the whole success.html steps).  Anyone know a magic way to do that?

Comment: Well before you go there, you might want to try setting a static route in your router for www.apple.com. If it's the DNS timing out, that should fix the problem.

Answer (score -1):

In Settings → Wi-Fi, when you click the small *i* next to the network name, you can disable the automatic login setting, then the window should not be shown again.

Comment: But this will also mean the phone won't auto-join that mifi, right?